# Android databinding use raw MutableLiveData

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding, android-livedata

I want to pass a `MutableLiveData<Integer>` in a ClickListener, without the databinding automatically unwrapping it and just passing the `Integer`. Is there a special syntax to tell databinding to leave `MutableLiveData<Integer>` alone and just pass it as is ?
here is an example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="@{v -> viewmodel.doSomething(viewmodel.myMutableLiveData1)}" />
```

I would then go ahead and change the value of `myMutableLiveDataX` in `doSomething()`

The reason for the whole thing is, I have multiple `myMutableLiveDataX`s and they are all doing same, but to different data, I don't want to create `doSomething1()` `doSomething2()` etc...

One possible, but clunky workaround would be of course to wrap the `MutableLiveData` in another Object and pass that one when the raw `MutableLiveData` is required and then use the getter on that object whenever the unwrapped data is used.

Comment: If you are calling method from viewmodel, and passing data from viewmodel, then why pass data at all? Simply use the date inside the method that you are calling?

Comment: @SamirSpahic the reason is I want to use the same method on different data, e.g. `doSomething(data1)`, `doSomething(data2)`, `doSomething(data3)` etc.
If I use the data directly in the method, I'd need to repeat the same method multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, This is what you need

In Kotlin

```
fun doSomething(data: MutableLiveData<Any>){
        val value=data.value
        when(value){
            is String->{}
            is Int->{}
            is YourCustomType->{}
        }
    }
```

In Java

```
void doSomething(MutableLiveData<Object> data){
        Object value=data.getValue();
        if(value instanceof Integer){}
        else if(value instanceof String){}
        else if(value instanceof YourCustomType){}
    }
```

Comment: The issue isn't the `doSomething` method, but the auto-generated databinding code from the XML. It will automatically unwrap the `MutableLiveData<Object>` and there pass the `Object` directly